# Error code 937, SQL state 42000: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I do not know what is the problem

```
SELECT 
    DP.CODE_VALEUR CODE,
    MAX(VA.CODE_TYPE_VALEUR) CODE_TYPE_VALEUR,
    MAX(VA.NOM_VALEUR) STOCK_NAME,
    (SUM(COURS_ACQ_VALEUR) / SUM(QUANTITE_VALEUR)) CMP,
    MAX(DP.CODE_COMPTE) CODE_COMPTE,
    SUM(DP.QUANTITE_VALEUR) QTEVALEUR,
    round(SUM(DP.VALORISATION_BOURSIERE), 3) VALORISATION_BOURSIERE,
    round((SUM(DP.VALORISATION_BOURSIERE) / SUM(DP.QUANTITE_VALEUR)),
            3) COURS
FROM
    DETAILPORTEFEUILLE DP,
    VALEUR VA
WHERE
    DP.CODE_COMPTE IN (SELECT 
            P.CODE_COMPTE_RATTACHE
        FROM
            PROCURATION P
        WHERE
            P.IDWEB_MASTER = 8
                AND NVL(P.CAN_SEE_PORTEFEUILLE, 0) != 0)
        AND VA.CODE_VALEUR = DP.CODE_VALEUR
        AND DP.QUANTITE_VALEUR > 0
        AND DP.CODE_VALEUR = 'TN0007250012'
```

Comment: http://ora-937.ora-code.com/

Comment: You can aggregate rows only when you group them. So just add GROUP BY..

Comment: @ErikPragt IMHO, that's a bad recommendation. ora-code.com just lists the Oracle error messages without further explanation. I *never* got any useful information from that site.

Comment: I agree, but in this case it's exactly the cause. However, what I really meant was: this is very easily googleable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add

```
GROUP BY DP.CODE_VALEUR
```

Answer (score 1):

A SELECT list cannot include both a group function, such as AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, STDDEV, or VARIANCE, and an individual column expression, unless the individual column expression is included in a GROUP BY clause.

Drop either the group function or the individual column expression from the SELECT list or add a GROUP BY clause that includes all individual column expressions listed.

OR ADD

GROUP BY DP.CODE_VALEUR

Answer (score 0):

In order to use aggregate functions SUM, MAX etc. you need to tell the database to GROUP BY at least one column.